# Kabsch Algorithm for 2d to 3d Rotation and Translation

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, matching, point

My problem involves matching a set of 2d points to a set of 3d points, with known correspondence between the two. Basically I have points on an image, and I need the optimal translation and rotation to fit the points to a known 3d point cloud. Kabsch algorithm is originally meant for finding the best fit of 3d points to another point cloud, and there are implementations out there for 2d to 2d, but not something I can use. I do know it's possible, but just don't know how to go about it. I searched for code out there and came up empty. I'm programming in matlab at the moment, but any language would do.

Thank you.

Edit: The goal is getting a rotation and translation of the 3d point cloud to best match the 2d points when it is projected onto an image plane.

I should also mention that the 3d to 2d projection is done using a weak perspective.

Comment: Could you not regard your 2d points (x,y) as 3d (x,y,0)?

Comment: The 2d points are not a point cloud but a projection of the 3d points onto an image plane.

Comment: The problem is called 'registration' and there is a lot of literature on the 3D to 2D case. I'm on my phone so can't give a good answer but Google for object to image registration or 3d 2d point registration and you should get something useful

Comment: @MrE Were you referring to something like [this](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~atroccol/3DPhoto/3D-2D_registration.html) . It doesn't explain much though. What I am looking for is a good step by step explanation of how to get the rotation and translation. An somewhat good explanation of the 2d to 2d is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77462/finding-transformation-matrix-between-two-2d-coordinate-frames-pixel-plane-to-w) but I can't find 3d to 2d explained. I first learned how Kabsch works through matlab code, so would be nice to find an implementation or pseudocode.

Comment: No more help on this I'm guessing?

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you have a "plane" or a "line" of points, like the third dimension was 0. You could threat them like this, and use the tipicall kabsh algorithm of squared distance minimisation, don't you?

EDIT: maybe it's a nonsense, but what about projecting the 3d body to 2d coordinates, and do a 2d comparison? Computationally is expensive, so it includes exploring all the angles of the 3d object + projection, but it's easier losing one dimension by applying a projection, that adding a new dimenssion to a 2d point.

Comment: No, I don't think it's that simple. The 2d points are projections of the 3d points on an image plane. I think I might have screwed up my logic a bit when writing the question. I updated with an edit.

Comment: How do you transform the 3d into 2d? just projecting two of the dimensions and missing the third one? Ok sorry, you answered this in the previous comment!

Comment: Could you define briefly the problem you are trying to solve? Anything related to protein structure comparison?

Comment: The problem is of finding the 3d orientation of an object in an image. As an example, you could have a 3d model of a chair, and a picture of a chair. The image is labeled with points that match the models points, and I want to find the orientation of the chair in the picture.

Comment: Just saw your edit. As I mentioned before, there is a way to modify the Kabsch algorithm to do this efficiently, just that I don't know how. A brute force approach wouldn't be very nice. This is a higher level problem that has been solved, but I want to see the algorithm so I can learn from it. Thanks for the try.